# How to resolve 500 Message:An error has occurred while Accessing API from Azure?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-mobile-services

I am working with Azure Mobile Services API, my API on the local host running well. I have checked with the help of Swagger UI. but when I publish my API to azure then after that by accessing the API with Swagger I got this error.

> 500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
> http://xxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1

Now if I type this route: `http://xxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/doctor?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0`
to any table then I got the result;
why not with Swagger?

Help me to get on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your `XML file` is available on the same location as you have defined in the swagger UI properties on Azure.
I would highly recommend to generate your swagger xml file

**Steps :**

1. Right click on webapi project
2. Properties => build tab
3. Output section  - in different folder other than bin.

**For example :** `App_Start\\{ProjectName}.xml`